# Using console to install SDK

Tags: php

I am trying to install Klarna payment systems on my web-site. I've never used a console to install anything. But the documentation confidently gives instructions as if this stuff is widely known. Can anyone tell me what I actually need to do. I have faced an unfortunate complication: I am using Windows for my local server.  And here are the instructions for installing the payment system:

https://developers.klarna.com/en/gb/kco-v3/sdk/php/

In the "Installation and usage" it says:

To install the PHP SDK from the Central Composer repository use composer:

```
composer require klarna/kco_rest
```

Question:

As far as I understand I need to download something first and then place it somewhere. But I digged through the documentation and found nothing to download at all. I tried to enter the given string in PHP console - nothing happens. Is the documentation incomplete, or am I way too dumb to understand what they want from me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Along with thousands of answers in stackoverflow and blogposts, here is my take on what you need to know

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) is a tool for dependency management in PHP. which means its a software like any other software. It allows you to specify the libraries for your PHP project depends on and it will manage (install/update) them for you.

It helps us installing/updating various requirements/components for our application such as Laravel framework, Doctrine, or in your case **klarna/kco_rest**.

In order to use composer you have to [install composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) first. Then you need to [initialize composer](http://weaintplastic.github.io/web-development-field-guide/Development/Frontend_Development/Setting_up_your_project/Setup_Dependency_Managers/Composer/Initialize_Composer_on_a_new_Project.html) for your project. So that whichever libraries you need can be installed via composer. and those libraries will get autoloaded, that means you can use those library specific classes, using the `use` statements like following,

`use Vendor\Lib\Class`